# Get EWS appointment using finditem() and getitems()

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm using finditem() and getitems() to return the calendaritemtype and loaded properties. This call is made exactly 10 seconds after user submits appointment and I can confirm I recieve an accept from the room or resource like a second after its submitted. Due to high traffic on my site, I'm required to check the appointment immediately after creation to get an accept or decline from the room, this prevents simultaneous booking. I've pieced together the method below to return attendee response so I can pass on true or false as confirmed. When I run this method It lists alot of appointments but NEVER the one that I just created.

Keep in mind I recieve an ACCEPT from the room immediately, I just cant get to the calendaritemtype (appointment) to get the ACCEPT programmatically..

1. Do I need to tweak my findItem search so I can return my calendaritemtype (appointment)?
2. Is synchronization something I need to consider?

I see the Attendees in my properties for the Item at hand, its just not the right item.

Here's the method I speak of:

```
public static ResponseInfo GetCalendarEvents(ExchangeServiceBinding esb, DateTime starttime, Reservation res, Patron pat)
{
    var startts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var endts = new TimeSpan(0, 23, 59, 0);
    var endtime = new DateTime();

    //set timespan of date to beginning of dayy
    starttime = starttime.Date + startts;
    endtime = starttime.Date + endts;

    // Form the FindItem request.
    var findItemRequest = new FindItemType();
    var ce = new ResponseInfo();
    var calendarView = new CalendarViewType
    {
        StartDate = starttime,
        EndDate = endtime,
        MaxEntriesReturned = 100,
        MaxEntriesReturnedSpecified = true
    };

    findItemRequest.Item = calendarView;

    // Define which item properties are returned in the response.
    var itemProperties = new ItemResponseShapeType { BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.IdOnly };

    // Define the traversal type.
    findItemRequest.Traversal = ItemQueryTraversalType.Shallow;

    // Use the Default shape for the response. 
    findItemRequest.ItemShape = itemProperties;

    // Identify which folders to search to find items.
    var folderIDArray = new DistinguishedFolderIdType[2];
    folderIDArray[0] = new DistinguishedFolderIdType();
    folderIDArray[0].Id = DistinguishedFolderIdNameType.calendar;

    // Add folders to the request.
    findItemRequest.ParentFolderIds = folderIDArray;

    try
    {
        // Send the FindItem request and get the response.
        var findItemResponse = esb.FindItem(findItemRequest);

        // Next, enumerate through the Items returned by FindItem.
        foreach (FindItemResponseMessageType responseMessage in findItemResponse.ResponseMessages.Items)
        {
            if (responseMessage.ResponseClass == ResponseClassType.Success)
            {
                var mailboxItems = (ArrayOfRealItemsType)responseMessage.RootFolder.Item;

                for (int itemCount = 0; itemCount < mailboxItems.Items.Length; itemCount++)
                {
                    var inboxItem = mailboxItems.Items[itemCount];
                    // Call GetItem on each ItemId to retrieve the 
                    // item's Body property and any AttachmentIds.
                    // Form the GetItem request.
                    var getItemRequest = new GetItemType
                    {
                        ItemShape = new ItemResponseShapeType { BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.AllProperties }
                    };

                    // AllProperties on a GetItem
                    getItemRequest.ItemIds = new ItemIdType[1];
                    getItemRequest.ItemIds[0] = inboxItem.ItemId;

                    var getItemResponse = esb.GetItem(getItemRequest);

                    // We only passed in one ItemId to the GetItem
                    // request. Therefore, we can assume that
                    // we got at most one Item back.
                    var getItemResponseMessage = getItemResponse.ResponseMessages.Items[0] as ItemInfoResponseMessageType;
                    if (getItemResponseMessage != null)
                    {
                        if (getItemResponseMessage.ResponseClass == ResponseClassType.Success && getItemResponseMessage.Items.Items != null && getItemResponseMessage.Items.Items.Length > 0)
                        {
                            inboxItem = getItemResponseMessage.Items.Items[0];

                            var e = (CalendarItemType)inboxItem;


                            if (e.Start == res.Start && e.End == res.End)
                            {
                                foreach (AttendeeType at in e.RequiredAttendees)
                                {
                                    //attendee must accept meeting & attendee email must match email in reservation
                                    if (at.ResponseType == ResponseTypeType.Accept && at.Mailbox.EmailAddress == res.EmailAddress)
                                    {
                                        ce.Mailbox = at.Mailbox.EmailAddress;
                                        ce.ApptStart = e.Start;
                                        ce.ApptEnd = e.Start;
                                        ce.ApptResponse = ResponseTypeType.Accept;

                                        return ce;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ce.Mailbox = "getItemResponseMessage.ResponseClass";
                            return ce;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ce.Mailbox = "getItemResponseMessage is null";
                        return ce;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ce.Mailbox = "findItemResponseMessage is null";
                return ce;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ServiceRequestException ex)
    {
        Logger.LogStringError("****Error****: GetCalendarEvents()...ServiceRequestException= " + ex);
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        Logger.LogStringError("****Error****: GetCalendarEvents()...WebException= " + ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogStringError("****Error****: GetCalendarEvents()...Exception= " + ex);
    }

    return ce;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: My Item was in the system all along BUT I couldnt find it because of these reasons...

1. Exchange stores times in UTC format so if I left my window to be one day (i.e 12am - 11:59pm) and I was looking for an appointment between 9-11 pm, the finditem() wouldnt catch the appointment because it was defined as UTC time in exchange (in my case UTC time is 5 hours ahead, so the appointment was stored as 2-4am). Make sure you make your window big enough to handle the difference in UTC time...

   ```
     var calendarView = new CalendarViewType
                      {
                          StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                          EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                          MaxEntriesReturned = 100,
                          MaxEntriesReturnedSpecified = true
                      };
   ```
2. Make sure that when you're comparing property times of the item, convert time tolocaltime()...

   ```
     if (e.Start.ToLocalTime() == res.Start && e.End.ToLocalTime() == res.End)
     {
          foreach (AttendeeType at in e.RequiredAttendees)
          {
    //attendee must accept meeting & attendee email    must match email in  reservation
              if (at.ResponseType == ResponseTypeType.Accept  && at.Mailbox.EmailAddress == res.EmailAddress)
              {
                  ce.Mailbox = at.Mailbox.EmailAddress;
                  ce.ApptStart = e.Start;
                  ce.ApptEnd = e.Start;
                  ce.ApptResponse = ResponseTypeType.Accept;
                  calevents.Add(ce);
              }
          }
      }
   ```